# Change Debug messages for Oracle Developer Tools in C# to English

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio

I downloaded and installed [Oracle Development Tools for Visual Studio 2015](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odacmsidownload-2745497.html) and for some reason when i debug code, i see all the Oracle related exceptions/messages, while stepping into or over code segments in C#, to be in German.

My PC initially had the German version of Windows 7 installed, but then i later installed the English language pack and set the default language of Windows to English, thereby setting the language of all MS products to English. All my regular C# exceptions, along with my VS itself, are in English, except for the Oracle errors and i, truly at my wits end.

I have checked all the available solutions on StackOverflow and none of them solve my issue.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Cheers,
Vivek

Comment: Have you installed a German language pack for .NET or Oracle tools?

Comment: In Windows 7 you can specify a different *UI* language in addition to the user and system locale. That controls the UI culture, which is used to load localized resources for .NET programs. In previous versions, the UI language couldn't be changed. I think the setting is in the `Keyboard and Languages` tab of the regional settings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several options.

After connected to Oracle you can execute

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE = 'American';
```

or set default language in your Registry at

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_{Oracle Home Name}\NLS_LANG`, resp.

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_{Oracle Home Name}\NLS_LANG`

or set `NLS_LANG` as Environment Variable.

See [NLS_LANG FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/globalization/nls-lang-099431.html) to get more information about `NLS_LANG`

In case you use the ODP.NET **Managed** Driver, have a look at 
[Data Provider for .NET Developer's Guide: Globalization Support](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E51173_01/win.122/e17732/featGlobal.htm#ODPNT437)

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP asks. Unless Oracle Tools ignore the regional settings and use NLS_LANG